# SQL Server - Split rows in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I would like to split the rows of a column given a separator (in my specific case, it would be 0), treating the column like a traditional linked list (e.g. a Python list). 
Then, obtain the mode of each cluster and replace each value of the cluster with his mode.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
| ID | Data
+----+-------
| 1  |  0
| 2  |  0
| 3  |  0
| 4  |  1
| 5  |  2
| 6  |  2
| 7  |  0
| 8  |  0
| 9  |  1
| 10 |  2
| 11 |  1
| 12 |  0
```

The associated Python's list would be:

```
Data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

The clusters would be the following:

```
Cluster[0] = [1, 2, 2]
Cluster[1] = [1, 2, 1]
```

The desired output as a table would be:

```
| ID | Data
+----+-------
| 1  |  0
| 2  |  0
| 3  |  0
| 4  |  2
| 5  |  2
| 6  |  2
| 7  |  0
| 8  |  0
| 9  |  1
| 10 |  1
| 11 |  1
| 12 |  0
```

Comment: What do you mean by `mode` in "the mode of each cluster"?

Comment: @ZoharPeled He means the value that appears the most times in the cluster/group

Comment: Kudos for making me think.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen an SQL question Gordon can't answer faster than I can read :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of zeros before each value and then using window functions to identify the mode:

```
select t.id, t.data,
       (case when data = 0 then 0
             else first_value(data) over (partition by grp order by cnt desc)
        end) as mode
from (select t.id, t.data, t.grp,
             (case when data = 0 then 0
                   else count(*) over (partition by grp, data)
              end) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when data = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/7027) is a SQL Fiddle.

I don't like all the `case when data = 0` logic, but it appears necessary given the way that the groups are defined.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Data] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,0)
,(2,0)
,(3,0)
,(4,1)
,(5,2)
,(6,2)
,(7,0)
,(8,0)
,(9,1)
,(10,2)
,(11,1)
,(12,0)

;with cte as (
Select ID
      ,Data
      ,Grp = sum(Flg) over (Order by ID) * sign(Data)
 From  ( Select *
               ,Flg = case when lag(Data,1,Data) over (Order by ID) = 0 and Data<>0 then 1 else 0 end  
          From  @YourTable 
       ) A
)
Select A.ID
      ,Data = isnull(B.Data,0)
 From cte A
 Left Join (Select Top 1 with Ties Grp,Data,hits=count(*) 
             From  cte 
             Where Data<>0 
             Group By Grp,Data 
             Order By Row_Number() over (partition by Grp order by count(*) desc) 
           ) B
   on A.Grp=B.Grp
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Data
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   0
8   0
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  0
```